# Why does valgrind say there are no leaks, even though #allocs != #frees?

Tags: c++, valgrind

I am writing a C++ program and noticed something interesting, where valgrind says this program has no leaks, but at the same time is saying that the number of allocs is not equal to the number of frees.

This just seems bizarre to me:

```
==8676== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8676==    in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8676== total heap usage: 42 allocs, 45 frees, 78,672 bytes allocated
==8676==
==8676== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

I haven't studied this much, but if heap memory is not freed, it is *lost*. Since we no longer have pointers to it, it will never be free. So why this?

Edit: So in this case we have more frees than allocs. Valgrind does show errors in the form of "invalid writes". But probably my misunderstanding came from the fact that I thought allocs and frees always had to equal each other to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Looks like you're showing *more* frees than allocs here...

Comment: Note that you have *more* frees than allocs! If you call `free` with a NULL pointer, it does nothing! However, without code, I can't really offer any further explanation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: The output is reporting the number of times new and delete were *called*, not the number of times they appear in the code.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury does `delete nullptr;` count as a call to delete? (of course in code i will rather be `delete some_ptr;` and `some_ptr` happens to be `nullptr`)

Comment: if you fix your misunderstanding (frees vs allocs)  this would be a nice question. If you also add a [mcve] this would be a very nice question ;)

Comment: The "no leaks are possible" is due to **all heap blocks were freed**.

Comment: @idclev463035818: Looks like it's complicated.  Trying just now, if I directly set something to nullptr and then `delete` it, valgrind shows a phantom allocation and one delete.  Same result if I `delete` it twice.  However if I create something with `new` and `delete` it twice, it shows 1 allocation and 2 frees.  This is is situation likely to come up in real code, often as the result of copying something holding a raw pointer that `delete`s it in the destructor.

Comment: If your program contains undefined behavior (e.g. the "invalid writes" that valgrind reports) that might affect the accuracy of valgrind's heap tracking.  I suggest fixing the undefined behavior first, and then running valgrind again to see if it still reports more free than allocations.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, those counts are for how many times the function is called, not how many times the memory was actually freed. `free()` is specified as to accept `NULL` and to no-op if so, so that count most likely includes such cases.

Otherwise, your program would (most likely but not always) crash with a double-free error of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see exactly what Valgrind is counting, run with `--trace-malloc=yes` (don't do that with a big app, it should be OK in this case with ~40 each allcs and deallocs). You may want to use `c++filt` on the output, as Valgrind will print mangled names.